# Objective C - Image to full screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to put one image in full screen but my result is this:

- First screen:
  [image]

-Full screen: (in this screen the image are in landscape (rotated))
[image]

I want that in full screen the picture fills all the screen.

My function:

```
-(void)imgToFullScreen{

    if (!isFullScreen) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            //save previous frame
            prevFrame = imagen.frame;
            //[imagen setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
            [imagen setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,415)];

            UIImage * portraitImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: imagen.image.CGImage];
            UIImage * LandscapeImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: portraitImage.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationRight];

            imagen.image = LandscapeImage;

            tabbar.hidden = YES;
            logo.hidden = YES;
            self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;


        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = true;
        }];
        return;
    }
    else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            [imagen setFrame:prevFrame];
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:tarjeta.imagen options:0];
            imagen.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            tabbar.hidden= NO;
            logo.hidden = NO;
            self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;



        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            isFullScreen = false;
        }];
        return;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: You want a picture with landscape orientation to fill the screen which is in portrait orientation? Do you want it stretched or do you want to keep the aspect ratio? If you want to keep the aspect ratio, do you want it cut off (at the sides) or do you want white space (at top and bottom)? Which content mode is your uiimageview currently set to?

Comment: I want a picture with landscape orientation to fill the screen which is in portrait orientation and I want it stretched.

Comment: I get that with my code but showing the NavigationBar and I also need to hide it.

Comment: Hiding the navigation bar is possible, but is another question. The same for the status bar.

Comment: Yes I know it's possible, but when I hide the navigation bar the problem occurs.

Comment: Well, layout the UIImageView so that its frame covers the full screen and set its contentmode to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill. For more options of contentmode see the docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: What problem occurs when you hide the navigation bar? You may need to reset the UIImageView's frame so that it actually covers the area that used to be occupied by the navigation bar.

Comment: Is it not enough to define the frame?

Comment: When you set it to (0,0,320,415) then you get (0,0,320,415) and that is (about) what your screenshot shows.

Comment: But If you see the screenshots, the frame is the same in both pictures.

Comment: Yes, it is about (0,0,320,415). That is what you have set. That is NOT the size of the full screen.

Comment: What contentmode do you use?

Comment: if I put (0,0,320,480) occurs the same.

Comment: (0,0,320,480) works on iPhone4 and older.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't rotate it with transform simply?

```
imagen.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90.0);
```

Set the frame to your keyWindow dimensions (which is always portrait), rotate if needed, while content mode is aspect fill.

I'd put the image to a new modal view controller anyway, with the only purpose of showing the image it initialized with. So you'd won't need to hide navbar, and use flags, etc. Simply dismiss the controller when appropriate. Your code would read much better:

```
-(void)imageViewTouchedUp:(UIImageView*) imageView
{
     [[[ImageViewerViewController alloc] initWithImageView:imageView]
      presentViewController:self
      animated:self.presentAnimated
      completion:nil];
}
```